# StackOverflowError on Solaris but not on Linux/Windows

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I have a Java application that parses a large xml schema (.xsd) using Xerces that runs fine on Linux and Windows but gives a StackOverflowError on Solaris, with exactly the same inputs and configuration. I know that Xerces uses recursion to validate xml schemas but since it didn't give any problems on Windows and Linux I was pretty confident that it run everywhere.

Why does this happen? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp), the default stack size depends on the OS.

**Sparc:** 512

**Solaris x86:** 320 (was 256 prior in 5.0 and earlier) *(update: According to [this page](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4689767), the size of the main thread stack comes from the ulimit.  The main thread stack is artificially reduced by the vm to the -Xss value)*

**Sparc 64 bit:** 1024

**Linux amd64:** 1024 (was 0 in 5.0 and earlier) *(update: The default size comes from ulimit, but I can be reduced with -Xss)*

**Windows:** 256 (also [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4689767))

You can change the default setting with the **-Xss** flag. For example:

```
java ... -Xss1024k ... <classname>
```

would set the default stack size to 1Mb.

Comment: Windows default stack size is 1MB. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Actually, I think Windows stack size is 256K according to http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4689767

That page also clarifies this question a bit. I'll update my answer with that info.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Hotspot VM parameter defaults [may be different](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp) for different architectures. I would determine the defaults under Windows/Linux, and try setting those for Solaris.

For example:

> -XX:ThreadStackSize=512 - Thread Stack Size (in Kbytes). (0 means use default stack size) [Sparc: 512; Solaris x86: 320 (was 256 prior in 5.0 and earlier); Sparc 64 bit: 1024; Linux amd64: 1024 (was 0 in 5.0 and earlier); all others 0.]

(I'm not suggesting this particular parameter is the problem. Merely highlighting its differences under different OSes)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the default maximum stack size differs between platforms.

You can specify the stack size using the -Xss command line to the JVM, e.g.

java -Xss256k

For a 256k stack.  This is allocated on a per-thread basis.

Answer (score -1):

Quote from javadoc:

**StackOverflowError**:
Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

How big a stack is, created for each method, is **implementation dependent**. That's the reason.